# Sinning and G-d's will, what's wrong with this logic?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, sin

1. Nothing happens against Hashem's will.
2. Ergo, when one sins, that's also Hashem's will.
3. Yet we know that Hashem wants us not to sin, so it's against His will.

Contradiction?

Comment: He wants us to have free will, which allows us to sin, which he doesn't want us to do

Comment: If 1 is true, then the sin itself (the act of sinning) must also be something according to His will. This is just a logical consequence of 1.

Comment: You're just asking how we have free will if Hashem decides everything

Comment: We have free will. Yet G-d does not like it when we sin - yet - if Hashem removed our free will we would be like robots and they would be no test and we would start to complain that we don't have free will (like how we complain that we don't have the right to vote even though we may vote against our own interest at times).

Comment: You might be interested in the thought of [R. Mordechai Yosef Leiner of Izbica](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Yosef_Leiner). To quote from Wikipedia’s summary, “[I]f everything is determined by God, then even sin is done in accordance with God's will.”

Comment: @JoelK : Interesting...so that would support the truth of statement 2 above. Yet there's still the issue of it contradicting 3.

Comment: @user9806: Izhbitz is a real edge-of-the-envelope philosophy on this one. In short, they believe that the only real sin is thinking that you acted against His Will. Which is why the gemara says that an aveirah lishmah -- an sin performed for the sake of heaven, can be more valuable than a mitzvah performed for ulterior motive. I am not saying I understand this. I mean, isn't the act of thinking one sinned itself subject to your question?

Comment: This is explained in Chabad Chassidus by the difference between חיצוניות הרצון - externally expressed will (for which #1 is true) and פנימיות הרצון - internally desired result (for which #3 is true). The idea is too lengthy and complex to introduce in a Mi Yodea answer without background, but that is where you would want to start looking for a resolution. Externally expressed will is simply indifferent: https://www.sefaria.org/Job.35.6?lang=bi It is the internal desired result for the world that remains (as of yet) unfulfilled - but it ultimately will be.

Comment: You said nothing happens against Hashem's will. Will and approval are different. Just because Hashem lets something happen does not mean He likes it and wants it to be that way.

Comment: @MichaBerger But surely the Izhbitz wouldn't condone someone, say, eating a cheeseburger while thinking that this is "also G-d's Will"? So then what's the nafka mina of their statement?

Comment: IMHO, (a simplified version of @Yishai) your syllogism is only relevant for the anthropomorphic [approach to] G-d, a "slimmed-down" G-d, G-d that acts within our space-time framework. G-d that has a will similarly to humans that can or cannot be fulfilled, etc. Once you think of a "meta"-G-d, G-d that "exists" beyond our space-time, it is hard to ascribe Him any human qualities, incl. will.

Comment: @user9806: Don't know, not Izhbitz. But there is a difference in attitude. Does a hashkafic point need more than that? This isn't halakhah, where a nafqa mina lemaaseh is a defining criterion.

Comment: @Shmuel: but if we didn't have free will so that we could never act against Hashem's Plan, we wouldn't complain about the lack of free will. We would never choose to.

Comment: @MichaBerger: I can see your point, but human nature is to complain. (Maslow's hierarchy of needs.) So we may still end up complaining to G-d that we don't have free will and demand to have it. On the flip side, if we were created like robots, then we may never ask for free will. The angles complained when G-d made Adam. Adam has the potential to sin (break HaShem's Will). If I recall correctly, Hashem's Will means to know thy G-d. Yes, Adam could sin but, he had the opportunity to know and love G-d. Angels don't have free will and just exist. We have the opportunity to live.

Comment: @Shmuel: But that wouldn't hold true after such a radical change like human nature without free will. Peace and Truth only protested the creation of Adam because Hashem wanted them to. Or, to unpack the medrash -- people lower the peace and honesty in the world, but as we develop our capacity for peace, we will eventually achieve both. Okay, I see I'm not going to fit the idea into this format. It's in the introduction to the Qetzos haChoshen.

Comment: @Shmuel: To put it another way... If we had been created without free will, that's because lack of free will and evil were the better choice, which means there is no reason for a being that only does G-d's will to protest. Unlike the creation of humanity, which had a short-term setback to two ideals for and it's those ideals that metaphorically "complained".

Answer (score 8):

Very short answer: Hashem wants creative beings in His own "Image" more than He wants any particular event.*

So far that's just a paraphrase of [Loewian's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/107179/1570).

We can go one step closer to the ineffable "Mind" of G-d and explore why that would be.

First, the Greatest Good is G-d Himself. Your person who cannot sin isn't receiving that Good, because who he is is compelled by Another. Hashem has total Freedom of Will; being able to enjoy the good of being in His Image would require allowing people at least *some* freedom of will.

Yes, fewer people would be hurt by others. But the total good in the world would go down.

Second, if we didn't have free will, and we were all automata, would any of the Good He bestows on us be worth anything? Who would be the recipients of his good if humans and grass are only quantitatively different? We needed to be moral agents if Hashem's goal of providing good to others is to be have "others" to be good to.

So, not only would the total good go down, any meaningful definition of good would go down to zero!

---

* One might argue that the above statement about Hashem's preference is only **almost** always true. And so the Exodus happening was something Hashem wanted more than Par'oh's being in His Image. Thus Hashem "hardened his heart." The question usually asked, how that was fair to Par'oh to deprive him of a chance to do *teshuvah*, is a somewhat different one and out of scope.

(**I think "hardened" is a poor translation of either "הכבדתי" or "החזקתי", but that's its own topic. I went with common usage.)

Comment: But I wouldn't try convincing a Holocaust survivor of any of this.

Answer (score 6):

**Rambam [Hilchot Teshuvah 5:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=5&halocha=4&hilite=)**

> ואל תתמה ותאמר היאך יהיה האדם עושה כל מה שיחפוץ ויהיו מעשיו מסורים לו וכי יעשה בעולם דבר שלא ברשות קונו ולא חפצו והכתוב אומר כל אשר חפץ ה' עשה בשמים ובארץ דע שהכל כחפצו יעשה ואף על פי שמעשינו מסורין לנו כיצד כשם שהיוצר חפץ להיות האש והרוח עולים למעלה והמים והארץ יורדים למטה והגלגל סובב בעיגול וכן שאר בריות העולם להיות כמנהגן שחפץ בו ככה חפץ להיות האדם רשותו בידו וכל מעשיו מסורין לו ולא יהיה לו לא כופה ולא מושך אלא הוא מעצמו ובדעתו שנתן לו האל עושה כל שהאדם יכול לעשות
>
> A person should not wonder: How is it possible for one to do whatever he wants and be responsible for his own deeds? - Is it possible for anything to happen in this world without the permission and desire of its Creator as [Psalms 135:6] states: "Whatever God wishes, He has done in the heavens and in the earth?"
>
> One must know that everything is done in accord with His will and, nevertheless, we are responsible for our deeds.
>
> How is this [apparent contradiction] resolved? Just as the Creator desired that [the elements of] fire and wind rise upward and [those of] water and earth descend downward, that the heavenly spheres revolve in a circular orbit, and all the other creations of the world follow the nature which He desired for them, so too, He desired that man have free choice and be responsible for his deeds, without being pulled or forced. Rather, he, on his own initiative, with the knowledge which God has granted him, will do anything that man is able to do.
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911903/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Five.htm), my emphasis)

Essentially, then, God's will is that humans have the free choice to act against His will.

Comment: As with the other posts this doesn't answer the question. The whole point is how can he will something to go against his will. If he wills it it is by definition not against his will

Comment: @DoubleAA I want you to upvote my answer. But I also want you to have the free choice to downvote my answer (or not vote at all). When designing the system I have to decide which of my wants is more important in case they come into conflict with each other.

Comment: Indeed when you have an apparent conflict you get to choose what you want in that case. You don't get to pick both.

Comment: @DoubleAA But I don't think that means that I don't *want* both. It just means that I can't *have* both.

Comment: Interesting opinion. (The point is this is all a stupid word game, and the question and these answers are all based on semantically ambiguous claims about what "want" some "thing" means. Just posting a different ambiguous phrase with a different intended meaning doesn't help the OP understand the logical problem. You have to explain to him.)

Comment: Think: "I want cookies." "Therefore, you want baking powder. Here's a cup of baking powder!" Which step is illogical?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps, but a large part of the answer is to, in fact, disambiguate the two concepts (the overall 'want', and the per event 'will')

Comment: @user9806 No, that's still missing my point entirely. Want and will are synonyms. The point is when we say we want something, we mean to say we want something under particular conditions and circumstances. I want baking powder baked in a cookie, not raw (and subject to other infinite particulars which generally go without saying and are inferred from context). Everything else on this page is just people playing silly word games that are a waste of everyone's time. You are participating by distinguishing between "want" and "will". It's just a word game of your own definitions to ambiguous words

Comment: It's not about the word "want" vs the word "will". I could've phrased 3 as "Yet we know that Hashem wills us not to sin", to the same effect. The point is that the question guides one to realize that there are two aspects of "will" - the ultimate desire (willing the what) and the manner of how it's accomplished (willing the how). So no, I don't think it's a waste of time to flesh out this dual nature of the concept of will.

Comment: @user still missing the point. There aren't multiple aspects of will. There are just different possible things to be willed in different circumstances. And you have obfuscated that dramatically with your language gymnastics. Its deciphering the semantic game that's a waste of time, not understanding the underlying issue which is of course itself useful.

Comment: What 'different circumstances' are you talking about here? There's only one circumstance here - Person X committed sin Y by doing Z. Was it G-d's Will that Z occurred? Yes, everything happens according to His Will. Was it also G-d's Will that he wouldn't sin? Also yes. But there is no contradiction, because these two aspects of Will are not mutually exclusive. One is ultimate goal, the other is the particulars of how the goal is accomplished.

Comment: @user9806 too narrow minded! One circumstance is X did Y in a context where helping him would not impede his free will or have some other particular consequence, another is where X did Y in a context where there is no greater good. The latter doesn't happen because God doesn't want it to and/or it's impossible. The former does because God wants it to. That's it. Only 1 will, and God always gets his way. You made up that God wants everyone to never sin ever. There is no such global want, nor multiple wills in a singular God. It all depends on circumstances. That's whats false about premise 3

Comment: That's the real technical answer here. Premise 3 is false. Thus no contradiction. Everything else on the page is just counterexamples where it is false, but couched in confusing word games. They're all dancing around the answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA why is premise 3 false?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas As pointed out repeatedly on this page, one case where God wants us to sin is where our not sinning would necessitate our losing our free will (ceteris paribus).

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to go to work this morning. I was tired and wanted to go back to sleep. Yet I put myself in the car and drove here, to work.

Let's try the question with my name rather than Hashem:

--

I did nothing today against my will.

Ergo, when I drive to work, that's also my will.

Yet we know that I did not want to go to work, so it's against my will.
Contradiction?

--

Can it be that both don't want to go to work, and do want to go to work?  Yes.
How? Results. Actions have consequences, results. I want the paycheck. I want to have done that which I do not wish to do, because I want the result.

He wants people to choose to follow Him. (Desired result - A paycheck)

To get there, one step in the HOW is giving people choice. (Method - Having a job)

The cost of choice is that some will make undesirable choices. (Cost - getting up, driving)

I want to go to work because I want the paycheck.
I don't want to go to work because I'm tired.  Being at work is part of my will, and something I'd prefer to avoid, at the same time.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ray and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  And since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Ray morris, I upvoted your answer because I think you answered this best. I will write my own answered but you answered this weel for your first answer. Way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions 1, and therefore 2, are at least partly false. That nothing happens against the divine will is only true when one looks at the contextual greater picture.  But without context i.e. at the "micro" level, choices are made against His will all the time, whenever people sin.  He allows this for the same reason that He allows suffering - as part of a larger purpose, primarily free will.

Saying that sin is according to His will is the same as saying that a parent who wants a child to learn to be independent, also wants the failures and suffering that inevitably result.

Comment: If He allows people to sin for whatever reason then isn't it His will?

Comment: 2 is not an assumption, it's just a logical consequence of 1.  Also, as a statement, 1 is either true (in its entirety) or not. If 1 is true : _nothing_ happens against His will, which is the same as saying that _everything_ happens according to His will, from which follows (by universal instantiation) that sin too is according to His will.  And if 1 is false, then that's saying "there exist some things/events that happen against His will". Which I suppose may be theologically problematic.

Comment: What is theologically problematic about G-d desiring that there be free will?

Answer (score 2):

From Rabbi Uri Sherqi:

1. In the words of Rabbi Tzvi Yehudah Kook, “Hashem needs their to be evil in the world. But, there’s no *mizwah* to volunteer.”
2. If someone were to commit a sin absolutely *Leshem Shamayim*, it may be considered a *mizwah*. The problem is that there is a *hazaqah* on mankind that sins *Leshem Shamayim* are incredibly rare. And, if you commit the sin not *Leshem Shamayim*, you’ll pay the price for it.

In short, we are required to abide by what Hashem told us is *mutar* and *assur*.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try an answer as well - I think the other answers have been converging on the same idea.

Short answer: #3 is a false statement.

Longer answer : The premise ("Hashem wants us not to sin") does not imply the conclusion ("sinning is against His will"). This is because, as has been alluded to by the other answers, the "wants not to sin" refers to the ultimate/overall G-d's desire of us choosing the right thing [this is the פנימיות הרצון]. So the word "want" in the premise does not refer to the same the same concept as the word "will" in he conclusion - the latter being the desire of G-d according to which all events happen [חיצוניות הרצון], which is assumption #1.

In other words, to realize the ultimate/long term desire of man doing good ("G-d wants us not to sin"), sinning is allowed to exist (i.e. it is according to His will).

Answer (score 0):

**Why does G-d allow evil?**

Maimonides states: Humans are given free will. If a person wants to take the good path and be righteous, he is free to do so; and if he desires to take the evil one and be wicked, he can do so ... The Creator doesn’t preordain
man to be good or evil (Mishneh Torah, Teshuvah 5:1–23).

The Babylonian Talmud (Berakhot 61a) explains: there are two letters yud in the Hebrew vayyitzer, “and He created” in Genesis 2:7. This denotes the existence of a yetzer ha’ra, an evil inclination, and a yetzer ha’tov, a good inclination.

**Why were humans given the ability to do evil?**

Perhaps it is G-d's will. In Hebrew sin is cheit or hamartia in Greek, which means "misstep" or “missing the mark," as if one is shooting an arrow and misses their target, hitting the outer rims instead of its center. What do we do when we shoot arrows and miss our targets? Do we cry, pound our chests, and ask forgiveness on special holidays? No. We reach into our bag or quiver, where an archer keeps his arrows, and attempt to aim again. Perceiving sin in this perspective, we find that we can learn from sin.

For example, if you work at the gym your muscles are going to ache the next day, but it is a good feeling, for that pain is an indication that your efforts are finally paying off. There is a saying "no pain, no gain." Thus, sin, in this way, is a learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I read a book called *Atlas Shrugged*. (Not a recommendation, just credit.) From it came a quote that has helped me a great deal in studying the OT in Hebrew. (non-Jew, former agnostic)

"Contradictions do not exist. Whenever you think you are facing a contradiction, check your premises. You will find that one of them is wrong."

I only use the phrase today of 'pseudo-contradiction' when seeking help from others to find the right pieces.

---

What was the event that brought death/sin/chaos into the world, according to Genesis? Disobedience.

As above, so below.

A scenario:

In the beginning, Elohim created/'birthed' an Entity. It was not Elohim's desire to father a child from this Entity for a time. The Entity willed to create without a consort/proper consort, and a fearsome/evil/lacking child was produced.

Elohim had created the Entity with Free Will. Elohim did not create Evil, but allowed the exercise of Free Will to bring Evil into the Heavens.

Elohim is Love. He did not purpose to leave the Heavens in such a dismal state; He had a plan - and we are It. Microcosm of the Macrocosm. Correcting from the bottom up, so to speak.

---

I offer this as the tool I found to get through a hurdle that once baffled me (and countless others). It was found in other ancient texts, and then opened my thinking in such a way as to see the application unfolding in the Hebrew OT.